# Hash a linux process in memory

Tags: linux, memory-management, process

I'm writing a program that will hash a running process, in memory, and compare it against a known hash (similar to how anti viruses work). What I want to concentrate on are the read-only sections, particularly data and executable sections. Not having done this in the past, how would I go about extracting this info?

Doing a simple `cat /proc/PID/maps`, I see the various sections. Do I need to parse this data manually or are there functions to extract this info?